# Laravel Socialite stopped working: "Socialite driver [zoom] not supported"

Tags: php, laravel, zoom-sdk

I was searching the web for two hours now... Removed vendor/, Cleared the app cache thousand times.. I already tried the double backslash thing, the leading slash thing:

```php
<?php
// app.php

    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */
     SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class,
```

and

```
// EventServiceProvider

protected $listen = [
    \SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
       // add more listeners (aka providers) here
       'SocialiteProviders\\Zoom\\ZoomExtendSocialite@handle',
    ],
//
```

The thing is: It just stopped working...

Any hints how to debug it?

Comment: Another hint: I just added (for testing reason) some other drivers... instagram, xing, twitter etc.. - allways the same: "Driver [enter the name] not supported when I do `Socialite::driver('xxxxxx')->stateless()->user();`

Comment: now i am so far, that I recognized `SocialiteWasCalled` is not being fired......